# Jquery: How do I stop the appending of my text onClick?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to stop this >> http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/8x2WX/

if you look at my jsfiddle, click on the required fields button, click it again.  You will see that it keeps appending [which is what the code is asking it to do] the fields that are empty.

What is a better way to do this? If user happens to click on button twice or as they are filling in the form and testing to see what is left, I want it to restart the display of validated text, not append. I tried text() and html(), but they don't work correctly.

```
$("#section-11,#section-12,#section-13,#section-1011").hide();

var projtype = new Array(
        {value : 'Cars', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-11'},
        {value : 'Planes', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-12'},
        {value : 'Boats', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-13'}
    );
$("select#1169").on('change',function () {
var thisVal = $(this).val();
 var sect_id ="";
     //$('fieldset[id!="mainSection"]').hide();
    $(projtype).each(function() {
$(this.sect_id).hide();
        if(this.value == thisVal) {
        $(this.sect_id).show();
        }
    });        
});

$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function() {
    //$("#holdErrMsg").append(" ");
    var requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find('input[class*="-required"], select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() {
      return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";  
    });
    if (requiredButEmpty.length) {
        requiredButEmpty.each(function () {

            $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
        });
    }
    return !requiredButEmpty.length;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see it the best/neat way of doing it is to create an element with an id like "errors_" + this.name and then update that element with the text that you would like to show:

```
var errorElementId = "errors_" + this.name;
if($('#'+errorElementId).length > 0) {
    var errorElement = document.createElement("p");
    errorElement.setAttribute("id", errorElementId);
    $("#holdErrMsg").append(errorElement);
} else {
    errorElement = $(errorElementId)
}
errorElement.text("Your fancy error string")
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can empty the place holder first by using `empty()`

```
$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function() {
    //$("#holdErrMsg").append(" ");
    $("#holdErrMsg").empty();
    var requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find('input[class*="-required"], select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() {
      return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";  
    });
    if (requiredButEmpty.length) {
        requiredButEmpty.each(function () {

            $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
        });
    }
    return !requiredButEmpty.length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just clear the `#holdErrMsg` at the beginning of validation?

```
$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function() {
    $("#holdErrMsg").empty();

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8x2WX/3/
Try that,I am emptying the error box before running the error checks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function() {
    //$("#holdErrMsg").append(""); not necessary
    var requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find('input[class*="-required"], select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() {
      return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";  
    });
    if (requiredButEmpty.length) {
        $("#holdErrMsg").empty(); // empty the message holder
        requiredButEmpty.each(function () {

            $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
        });
    }
    return !requiredButEmpty.length;
});
```

Comment: Wow - amazing, I think I tried everything, except obviously "empty".  Thank you!!!!